# Scaling a SVG rectangle position based on data

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am trying to create SVG view wherein, I need to place rectangles in a line based on ascending order of the data in the rectangle.

The rectangles should be placed at the appropriate distance from the left based on the difference of the values.

This is what I have got till now. However, I the rectangles are overlapping if I use the linear scale. Is there a way we can avoid overlapping of these rectangles?

Update:
We decided to display overlapping rectangles a level below and non-overlapping rectangles on the same level.  But the problem now is how to do the translation and place the rectangles below the other by updating the y axis. Overlapping needs to be decided upfront now and x and y coordinates needs to be determined for transformation. The problem is compounded as the rectangle size can vary based on the size of text inside it.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body { margin:0;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0; }
  </style>
 
</head>

<body>
    <script>
    var data = [{
      x: 20,
      y: 10,
      baseFare: 50,
      class : "L" 
    },
 {
      x: 100,
      y: 10,
      baseFare: 100,
      class : "K"
    }, {
      x: 200,
      y : 10,
      baseFare : 230,
      class : "R"
    },
 {
      x: 500,
      y : 10,
      baseFare : 1000,
      class : "R"
    },
 {
      x: 500,
      y : 10,
      baseFare : 400,
      class : "M"
    },
 {
      x: 500,
      y : 10,
      baseFare : 300,
      class : "N"
    },
  {
      x: 500,
      y : 10,
      baseFare : 380,
      class : "Q"
    }
               ];
      
 data = data.sort(function (a, b) {
            return d3.ascending(a.baseFare, b.baseFare);
        })

 var width = 2000;
 var height = 500;
  
    var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);
   
    var xExtent = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.baseFare; });
 var xRange = xExtent[1] - xExtent[0];
   
  var linearScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([0, 500])
            .domain([d3.min(data, function (d) {
                return d.baseFare;
            }), d3.max(data, function (d) {
                return d.baseFare;
            })]);
    
 var y = 10;
 
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      data[i].x = linearScale(data[i].baseFare);
  }

    var g = svg.selectAll('.someClass')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class","someClass")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
      });

    g.append("rect")
      .attr("width", 40)
      .attr("height", 40)
      .attr("rx", 10)
      .attr("ry", 10)
   .attr("stroke", "black")
   .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.8)
      .style("fill", "lightblue");
      
      g.append("text")
      .style("fill", "black")
   .attr("x", 15)
      .attr("y", 10)
      .style("alignment-baseline", "middle")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.class;
      })

    g.append("text")
      .style("fill", "black")
   .attr("x", 5)
      .attr("y", 30)
      .style("alignment-baseline", "middle")
      .text(function(d) {
        return "$" + d.baseFare;
      })
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Several ways I can think of -- but how do **you** want to avoid the overlap? Shift them down the page? Spread them out horizontally? Make the boxes narrower?

Comment: I want to spread them horizontally.

Comment: Unfortunately, you will have to sacrifice your requirement "The rectangles should be placed at the appropriate distance from the left based on the difference of the values." Modifying the rectangles placement horizontally based on overlap will break placement based on the difference of the values. To avoid overlap you can keep the order of the rectangles - but not the value based placement - unless you make the rectangles much smaller or increase the range of the scale so that there is no overlap.

Comment: As a possible alternative, you could raise any rectangle on mouseover so that a user could inspect each price/item without sacrificing placement based on value: https://jsfiddle.net/7fybwzta/

Answer (score 0):

When determining the x-translation to apply for a given rectangle, you can check if this x-translation would make this new rectangle overlap the previous one. If it's the case, then apply the translation of the previous rectangle plus the rectangle's width.

You can replace:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  data[i].x = linearScale(data[i].baseFare);
}
```

with:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  data[i].x = linearScale(data[i].baseFare);
  if (i > 0 && data[i - 1].x + 40 > data[i].x)
    data[i].x = data[i - 1].x + 41;
}
```

---

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body { margin:0;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0; }
  </style>
 
</head>

<body>
<script>

var data = [
  {
    x: 20,
    y: 10,
    baseFare: 50,
    class : "L" 
  },
  {
    x: 100,
    y: 10,
    baseFare: 100,
    class : "K"
  },
  {
    x: 200,
    y: 10,
    baseFare : 230,
    class : "R"
  },
  {
    x: 500,
    y: 10,
    baseFare : 1000,
    class : "R"
  },
  {
    x: 500,
    y: 10,
    baseFare : 400,
    class : "M"
  },
  {
    x: 500,
    y: 10,
    baseFare : 300,
    class : "N"
  },
 {
    x: 500,
    y: 10,
    baseFare : 380,
    class : "Q"
  }
];

data = data.sort(function (a, b) {
  return d3.ascending(a.baseFare, b.baseFare);
})

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 2000).attr("height", 500);

var xExtent = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.baseFare; });
var xRange = xExtent[1] - xExtent[0];

var linearScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([0, 500])
  .domain([
    d3.min(data, function (d) { return d.baseFare; }),
    d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.baseFare; })
  ]);
   
var y = 10;

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  data[i].x = linearScale(data[i].baseFare);
  if (i > 0 && data[i - 1].x + 40 > data[i].x)
    data[i].x = data[i - 1].x + 41;
}

var g = svg.selectAll('.someClass')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class","someClass")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  });

g.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 40)
  .attr("height", 40)
  .attr("rx", 10)
  .attr("ry", 10)
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.8)
  .style("fill", "lightblue");
  
  g.append("text")
  .style("fill", "black")
  .attr("x", 15)
  .attr("y", 10)
  .style("alignment-baseline", "middle")
  .text(function(d) { return d.class; })

g.append("text")
  .style("fill", "black")
  .attr("x", 5)
  .attr("y", 30)
  .style("alignment-baseline", "middle")
  .text(function(d) { return "$" + d.baseFare; })

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried something similar to what you have suggested above. However, I see one problem with it.  The positon of a rectangle with a particular value changes, if value of previous rectangles change.  For e.g if a rectangle with value 200 has the x coordinate as say 50. I would want it to be the same regardless of the values in the previous rectangles.

Comment: @ManojNaidu Not sure to understand. Could you update your question and your code with this new requirement?

Comment: Sorry, if I was not clear. What I mean is, can we ensure that the linear scale function returns a consistent value for the given data?  I see that if there is change in the data array, then the position of an existing value changes.